# Convert to base 42 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want convert a integer form base 10 to base 42 in Javascript,

by default Javascript can do to base 36 not more.

How can I do  to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Writing some code may help.

Comment: I don't have any code , I just want know how to do that ?

Comment: What would base 42 look like? It's not a used encoding. There is no definition for the characters used in base 42 encoding. Definitions only exists for 2 to 36, 32, 64, 85 and some others but not 42.

Comment: I found this converter but I you see what's look like .
I need base 42 because the backend that I need to fetch like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin you need some sort of symbol system to represent digits. In base 10 we have 10: `0 - 9`. In base 16 you have 16 `0 - 9` and `A – F`. Binary, of course you only have 2: `0` and `1`.

So for base 42 you'll need 42 types of digit. Since this just seems like an exercise maybe include upper and lower case digits (I'm sure there's a better scheme if you put your mind to it):

```
const symbols = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f".split(" ")
```

So the numbers 0 - 41 will be `0` through `f`. 42 will start at `10` 42**2 will be `100` etc.

To get the right-most digit, you can can take the number modulus the base. Then divide by the base (and take the floor) and do it again until your number is reduced to zero. With the above scheme here is counting to 100 base 42:

```js
const symbols = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f".split(" ")
function toBase(n, base){
  if (n === 0 ) return symbols[n]
  res = ""
  while (n) {
   res = symbols[n % base] + res
   n = Math.floor(n /  base)
  }
  return res
}

console.log(Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i) =>  toBase(i, 42)).join(", "))
```

Comment: `"01234...".split("")` (without spaces) will work as well.